# Backpropagation for manual neural network training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I need to train a neural network manually. Is there a simple way to get the derivatives of all of the learned parameters in the network (with respect to the output) via backpropagation, other than using the somewhat tedious

```
net[<|..., NetPortGradient[oport] -> ograd|>, NetPortGradient[iport]]
```

formulation to manually impose the necessary gradients as you pass backwards through the net?

I'm not even sure that it's possible to use `NetPortGradient` like that. And I'm assuming that

```
net[..., NetPortGradient[arraySpec]]
```

does not cause a backpropagation-and-storage-of-all-gradients operation behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi there, I think the "I'm not even sure that it's possible to use `NetPortGradient` like that" part has been answered under [your other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185948/netportgradient-output-port-restriction). In that case, and according to your first paragraph here, I think you already self-answered the "Is there a simple way to get the derivatives of all of the learned parameters in the network via backpropagation" part in your question -- if we agree that it's very hard if not impossible to find a way other than the one-liner you already demonstrated here.

Comment: ... Regarding the "somewhat tedious", as "tedious" is a bit subjective, I'm not sure what you are looking for here. Do you want to build the backpropagation from scratch?  If so I think a clarification / modification in your question might be good to help getting answers.