# NetPortGradient output port restriction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

The documentation for `NetPortGradient` says

> `net[<|..., NetPortGradient[oport] -> ograd|>, NetPortGradient[iport]]` can be used to impose a gradient at an output port `oport` that will be backpropogated to calculate the gradient at `iport`.

I understand that this introduces a constraint `x = ograd`. What exactly is `x`? The gradient of `oport` with respect to what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR

The `NetPortGradient[oport] -> ograd` is not

> the gradient of `oport` with respect to *what*,

it's

> the gradient of *what* with respect to `oport`.

### Over-simplified explanation

For a simple scalar example, suppose we have a neural network $\mathrm{net}$ mapping $in$ to $out$:

$$out=\mathrm{net}(in)\text{ ,}$$

and some post-computing $f$ (loss-function or following-up network, name it) involving $out$ as:

$$\mathcal{E}=f(out)\text{ .}$$

Then we have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\,\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}\,in}=\mathrm{net}'(in)\;\frac{\mathrm{d}\,\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}\,out}\text{ .}$$

For back-propagation, we know in advance:

- At which **particular value** (say, $in=3$) of $in$ we are doing the computing.
- The **numerical value** (say, $7$) of the endpoint's gradient at $in = 3$, i.e. $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}\,\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}\,out}\right|_{in=3}=7$. Note that we don't necessarily need to know the "formula" or "computing method" of $\frac{\mathrm{d}\,\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}\,out}$ in general way, just a numerical value 7 from whatever source we trust.

And we would like to know $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}\,\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}\,in}\right|_{in=3}$.

Now in Mathematica, that query is written as:

```
net[
     <| "in" -> 3, NetPortGradient["out"] -> 7 |>,
     NetPortGradient["in"]
]
```

When $f$ is the `Identity` function (i.e. $\mathcal{E}=out$), we have

```
net[<|"in"->3, NetPortGradient["out"]->1|>, NetPortGradient["in"]]
```

which is what the default way is computing (i.e. $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}\,out}{\mathrm{d}\,in}\right|_{in=3}$):

```
net[<|"in"->3|>, NetPortGradient["in"]]
```

### Example

```
net = ElementwiseLayer[#^2 &];
net[<|"Input" -> 3, NetPortGradient["Output"] -> 7|>, NetPortGradient["Input"]]
net[<|"Input" -> 3, NetPortGradient["Output"] -> 1|>, NetPortGradient["Input"]]
net[3, NetPortGradient["Input"]]
(*
  42.
  6.
  6.
*)
```